# How do you use PHP variables in mysqli query on the SELECT side?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
$mysqli -> prepare('SELECT $whatever FROM county_rates WHERE `id`=?')
```

For some reason, this does not work.  I know that the $whatever is correct because I'm defining it right before the statement.  When I replace the $whatever with the actual column name it works, but with the variable it does not.

I have also tried:

```
$mysqli -> prepare('SELECT ? FROM county_rates WHERE `id`=?')
```

and then defining the ? in the bind_param and all this returns is the column name itself.

Comment: Have you tried `{$whatever}`?

Comment: @blo only if he had a field name called `{$whatever}`

Comment: @Dagon does curly brackets only work for field names? As i have used them in `LIMIT` and other functions in the query, and it does work..

Comment: i don't think you understand the issue, the problem was he was using single quotes not double.

Comment: Complex (curly) syntax is also explained in the string section: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Oh, I get it, thanks for the reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use double quotes to have the variable expanded

```
$mysqli -> prepare("SELECT $whatever FROM county_rates WHERE `id`=?")
```

currently you are looking for **$whatever** not the contents of the variable.

you should familiarise yourself with this section of the manual: [Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Wow, thank you...crazy I've never ran into this.  I thought that double quotes and single quotes were relatively interchangeable in PHP.

Comment: php is loose, but not that loose

Comment: Sorry to bug you, last question...is it best practice to use double quotes then for most things like querys, echos, etc.?  Because I've been doing the exact opposite.

Comment: `echo 'fish'.$fish.'fish';` or `echo "fish $fish fish";` there are debates, you just pick what works for you. using double with no variable in side is a few nanosecounds slower. but has no 'real' world issue

Comment: What I've seen in PHP is that queries are usually written inside double quotes. Echo's and variable assignment are less agreed upon, but I generally use single quotes and concatenation for short strings or heredoc `<<<THEEND` for longer strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I tried it by myself and I hope it useful for you

```
<?php
$hostname = "your host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database name";
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

//test connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//declaring variable
$sql='name';

$prev=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT $sql FROM cs_product WHERE id=?");
    /*The types of data that can be bound [in bind_param()] are:
   i – integer
   d – double
   s – string
   b – blob
    */
$prev->bind_param('i',$_GET['pid']);
$prev->execute();
$prev->bind_result($name);
$prev->fetch();
$prev->close();

//showing the result
echo $name;

?>
```